# echo custom output when using Git over SSH

Tags: git, shell, ssh, git-bash

I use Gitolite and have set up a `POST_CREATE` trigger that clones a repository on another server and executes a couple of other commands. Some of these commands could take a while. This is the reason why I would like to `echo` some output so that the user actually sees what and if something happens at all.

The problem is that Git expects only its own output and I get a `Git Remote: Error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: …` error message. Git tries to interpret my `echo`’ed strings and bails out (see also [this related question](/questions/8170436)).

Is there a way to `echo` some custom output when using Git over SSH?

This is the setup I have:

```
Client <-> Gitolite Server <-> Second Server
```

I want the Client to see messages from scripts that are executed on the Gitolite server when a user starts a `git clone`.

Comment: Did you try echoing to stderr?

Comment: Not yet, I’ll try it and report back.

Answer (score 0):

If this 'clone' effort is for mirroring..

Please use gitolite's mirroring capability OR 
programme your own post-receive hook (not recommended)

I have use gitolite's mirroring extensively for my client's complex installation to replicate project all across the globe.

Comment: It’s not only mirroring, but also custom code. I actually don’t need the more complex Gitolite mirroring functionality. Your answer somehow misses the point, because I asked about generating output over a Git session. I just posted my setup for clarification.